# Form won't preventdefault after first

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to do a formular with different steps in my codeigniter with bootstrap4 project.

so I created a form:

```
<form id="myform" class="myform" action="#">
    ...
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myform").on("submit", function (event) 
    {
        console.log('submit .myform');
        event.preventDefault();
        ajax_call($(this).serialize(),'myform');
    });
});
```

The `"ajax_call"` is a function to send the data and handle the result - this function already works fine.

My problem is a little bit simpler but i cant solve it.

If I send the first form the log-message in the console `"submit .myform"` will display, the form wont submit and the `ajax_call-function` is running.

As a result I get the same (new) formula with some error messages from the validation.

So if I want to send this form again, the form will submitted and the `"$(".myform").on("submit", function (event) ..."` code wont work.

maybe its a problem of delegation? But for that I use the `".on"` in the js code!?

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing delegation, you need to your first selector to bind to a static element and the second parameter for the on function should be your form selector

```
$("body").on("submit", ".myform", function (event)
```

Comment: That shouldn't be needed if the `<form>` element itself is not replaced by `ajax_call` tho.

Comment: from **As result i get the same (new) formular** i assume he is replacing the whole form

Comment: I assumed that too, but I'm trying to help the OP do it in a simpler way :-D